# How to create a NSArray of unknown NSStrings?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsarray

For example, I have `@"John", @"Peter", ..., @"May"` and need to construct `NSArray`:

```
 [@"John", @"Peter", ..., @"May"]
```

The number of `NSString` is unknown and is taking from an import text file. As `NSArray` does not support appending new element, how can I create `NSArray`?

Thanks

UPDATE, let me rephrase the question. How can I create the dynamic array paremeter required by the follow function call?

```
 [segmentedAttributes attributesWithTitlesArray:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"John", @"Peter", @"May", nil]]
```

Comment: At the risk of sounding like a n00b, what is the purpose/need for the `nil`?

Comment: NSArrays cannot contain nil. You could use NSNull, but why do you need it to be nil terminated?

Comment: Please see UPDATE about why. It seems my question is wrong :-( the nil is not actually needed.

Comment: No problem, never mind. That's how you learn things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't.

You misunderstand the library behavior.

It is true that there is a convenience constructor `arrayWithObjects:` which is used thus:

```
NSArray* array=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Low", @"Medium", @"High", nil];
```

But this **does not** create an array with `nil` at the end. This `nil` is just to signify the end of the variable-length argument list. It just creates an `NSArray` with three elements, not four with the last one `nil`.

You just need to create an `NSArray` containing the required elements, and pass it to the library function. For example:

```
NSMutableArray*array=[NSMutableArray array];
while(...){
    ... get a string ...
    [array addObject: string];
}

SCSegmentedAttributes*attributes=[SCSegmentedAttributes attributesWithSegmentTitlesArray:array];
```

should work, without adding a `nil` or `[NSNull null]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't store `nil` in a Foundation collection class. Instead, you can use `[NSNull null]`. Use an `NSMutableArray`, then when you want to add your 'nil' object, use `[NSNull null]`.

Note that when you want to see if an object is `[NSNull null]` later on, that method will return the same instance every time, so you can do a direct point equality test, like this:

```
for (id anObject in myArray) {
    if (anObject == [NSNull null]) {
        NSLog(@"object is nil");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"object is not nil: %@", anObject);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

create mutable array then just use

```
NSString *myString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"ur new string"];

[myArray addObject:myString];
```

you have to add object type to array when adding new abject in mutable array.

hope this will help